# Reliable way to check for applications last ran from NTFS partition?

Tags: windows

When recovering a broken Windows system, I need to know which applications are actually used, so that I know which of them must be reinstalled and reconfigured (along with user's data) after the system has been recovered.

Is NTFS' Last Access info reliable for this purpose? If not, is there another way I can get a list of installed applications and how often they are used?

Ideally, it should also display the release version of each executable so that I can check with the editor where it saves users' data (configuration + documents).

Thank you.

Comment: By default, the last access time is not tracked any more.  I believe this change was introduced in Windows Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely unreliable. listing "program files" is somewhat indicative of what was installed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Why is it unreliable? Because Windows doesn't alway reset the Last Access when running an application?

Comment: The timestamp is indeed not necessarily updated when a program is run. If it is updated, this does not mean the program was actually used. It might have been running in the background without the user's knowledge, but the timestamp may also have been changed by some other application, such as a virus scanner.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So I'll just have to go through C:\Program Files\ and assume that they are no other applications installed elsehwere.

Comment: Microsoft guidelines suggest using program files path. for last 10 years or so.

Comment: Too bad there's not a reliable way to get the list based on actual use.

Comment: Tagging a file read would be a mine of gold for copyright profiters.